# You can't use `\eqno' in math mode

Tags: errors

Pls help me! I got some error message in TeXniCenter about this equation. I tried to look for errors in parentheses, but could not find.

```
\begin{equation}
P=\frac{\hat{U}\hat{I}}{2T}\int\limits^{T}_{0} \cos \left(\varphi \right)-\cos \left(2\omega {t}-\varphi \rigth)\,{dt}=\frac{\hat{U}\hat{I}}{2T} \left[{T\cos\left(\varphi\right)-\frac{\sin \left(2\omega {t}-\varphi \rigth)}{2\omega}}\right]^{T}_{0}
\end{equation}
```

This is the result after the errors: [image: result]

5 errors:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.223 ...ht)-\cos \left(2\omega {t}-\varphi \rigth
                                                  )\,{dt}=\frac{\hat{U}\hat{...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \sin \left (2\omega {t}-\varphi \rigth 
                                                  )
l.223 ...eft(2\omega {t}-\varphi \rigth)}{2\omega}
                                                  }\right]^{T}_{0}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing \right. inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \right .
l.223 ...eft(2\omega {t}-\varphi \rigth)}{2\omega}
                                                  }\right]^{T}_{0}
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! You can't use `\eqno' in math mode.
\endmathdisplay@a ...\df@tag \@empty \else \veqno 
                                                  \alt@tag \df@tag \fi \ifx ...
l.224 \end{equation}

Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.

! Missing \right. inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \right .
l.224 \end{equation}

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
```

Comment: typo: "rigth" -> "right"

Comment: Please, look at the first error message, not at the last one.

Comment: THX, OMG, it was a simple mistake.

Answer (score 6):

In such a case start with the first error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.223 ...ht)-\cos \left(2\omega {t}-\varphi \rigth
                                                  )\,{dt}=\frac{\hat{U}\hat{...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.
```

It says that the command at the end of the top line was never defined, right? That command is `\rigth`.

Fixing that by using the correct name `\right` will probably resolve your issues, the rest are most likely spurious errors as LaTeX tried to recover.